# javascript interpreter using javaCC

Tags: javascript, javacc

I have to make a JavaScript interpreter using javaCC, I wrote all the grammar rules, too many choice conflict though!! I tried LOOKAHEAD but I read then somewhere the LOOKAHEAD doesn't always solve the problem, so what do I do? it's really bad I mean I want to declare a variable.. just like ( var x; ) for example, it's not working .. I 'm pretty sure that the choice conflict is the problem.
for example:

```
void FunctionDeclaration():
{ 
}
{
  < FUNCTION > Identifier() "(" (ParameterList())? ")" "{" (FunctionBody())? "}"
}

void FunctionBody():
{
}
{
LOOKAHEAD(3)  FunctionDeclaration()
| (Statement())+
}

void Statement():
{
}
{
  LOOKAHEAD(3)
  Block()
| VariableStatement()
| EmptyStatement()
|  LOOKAHEAD(2) ExpressionStatement() 
| IfStatement()
| FunctionCall()
| IterationStatement()
| ContinueStatement()
| BreakStatement()
| ReturnStatement()
| WithStatement() 
| LabelledStatement()
| SwitchStatement()
| ThrowStatement()
| TryStatement()
| DebuggerStatement()
}
```

I can't write a ReturnStatement here because of that.

What do I do?

I already tried LOOKAHEAD here.. not working.

Comment: I can't figure out exactly what problem you have or what you've tried already to solve it. I'd suggest you cut the problem down to a minimal sized example grammar. I that doesn't help you solve the problem yourself, then post a new question using your minimal failing example.

Comment: Here's my [ongoing project](https://github.com/highsource/javascript-codemodel/blob/master/parser/src/main/javacc/ecmascript-262.jj) to develop a clean JavaScript/ECMAScript 5.1 parser in JavaCC. JavaScript is quite a problematic grammar.